# OpenWrt: Automatically disable WiFi if no network connection

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration, openwrt

I have a home network with multiple Wi-Fi access points providing redundant coverage (almost every spot in and around the house can see multiple APs). I just had a situation where a switch failed and one AP was no longer connected to the main network, however it was still accepting clients. Since it was the strongest AP in its area, everyone in that area was connected to the Wi-Fi but not the main network. If they went out of range of that AP then things worked just fine.

What I'd like to do is automatically disable the AP in the event of network failure (it cannot see the default gateway) or something similar.

I have searched Google and OpenWrt documentation and nothing seems to be what I'd like to do. I feel that this must be a simple thing and that I am just missing it. Can anyone give me some ideas or point me in the right direction?

I am running OpenWrt Chaos Calmer 15.05 and OpenWrt Backfire 10.03.1.